# MySQL query to get certain data between 2 times for the last 10 days

Tags: mysql

So i have a query that gets the lowest number and the highest number between 00:00 and 14:30 for a specific day.

```
SELECT MIN(low) AS lowestlow, MAX(high) AS highest 
FROM prices_15 
WHERE  start_date >= '2023-06-21' and end_date <= '2023-06-22'
    and cur_id=4 and time(start_date) <= time('14:30:00:00');
```

my question is what if i wanted to get the lowest and highest for 7 days, i.e between 2023-06-15 to 2023-06-22  bit like a foreach day get lowest and highest for each day between 00:00 and 14:30?

Comment: Add `GROUP BY DATE(start_date)` to get each date's min and max

Comment: Thank you so much, i cannot believe i missed that....hopefully it will help someone else who may suffer from coders block :) many thanks